# Array of buttons with Navigate on Firebase and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router-dom

What i'm trying to do here is:

-Getting all of my docs in my collection in my Cloud Firestore
-Putting them in an array of Buttons
-Having each button navigate onPress with the info from that button in particular, since i need it for the screen it navigates to

I did it before, but it was with a JSON and using array.map:

```
{aulas.map((aula)  => (
                <div key={aula.id} className="col-md-4" style={{paddingBottom: '10px', paddingTop: '5px'}}>
                <Button className={(aula.estado==='sucio'? 'btn btn-danger': 'btn btn-success')} 
                onClick={()=> navigate('/LimpiarCurso',
                {state: {id:aula.id,num_aula:aula.num_aula,año:aula.año,
                division:aula.division,horario_retiro:aula.horario_retiro}})}>
                    {aula.año}{aula.division}</Button>
                </div>
            ))}
```

And now i'm trying to rewrite that same functionality with the database

This is what i have so far:

```
export default function AdministrarCurso(){
    const navigate= useNavigate();
    function mostrarCursos(navigate){
        const querySnapshot = getDocs(collection(db, "Curso"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // console.log(doc);
            // console.log(doc.data());
            console.log(doc.get('anio')+doc.get('division'));
            <div className="col-md-4" style={{paddingBottom: '10px', paddingTop: '5px'}}>
            <Button 
            className={(doc.get('estado')==='sucio'? 'btn btn-danger': 'btn btn-success')} 
            onPress={()=> navigate('/LimpiarCurso',
            {state: doc.data()})}>
                {doc.get('anio')+doc.get('division')}
            </Button>
            </div>
    });
    }
    return(
        <Container> 
            <AppBar style={{background: 'transparent', boxShadow: 'none'}}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Button onClick={()=> LogOut(navigate)}>Cerrar Sesión</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
             <div className="row">
             
            {mostrarCursos()}
                 {/* Acá hay botones que se generan en base a la cantidad de documentos que tenga el forEach
//                 Que te redireccionan a la pantalla de Limpiar Curso
//                  */}
             </div>
         </Container>
     )
 }
```

Of course, it doesn't work, since first it said that "Objects are not valid as a react child" which i tried to change but i'm not exactly sure of how to do it, i tried with useState and useEffect but it didn't really work

Now it doesn't even work with querySnapshot (it says it's not a function)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React render cycle is synchronous. Fetch the documents in a `useEffect` hook and map the documents to an array of doc data and properties and save it into local state to be mapped to JSX in the component's render return. `getDocs` returns a Promise so it should be awaited.

```
export default function AdministrarCurso() {
  const navigate= useNavigate();

  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mostrarCursos = async () => {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Curso"));

      const docs = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        docs.push({
          data: doc.data(),
          anio: doc.get('anio'),
          division: doc.get('division'),
          estado: doc.get('estado'),
        });
      });
      setDocs(docs);
    };

    mostrarCuros();
  }, []);

  return(
    <Container> 
      <AppBar style={{background: 'transparent', boxShadow: 'none'}}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Button onClick={() => LogOut(navigate)}>
            Cerrar Sesión
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <div className="row">
        {docs.map(doc => (
          <div
            className="col-md-4"
            style={{ paddingBottom: '10px', paddingTop: '5px' }}
          >
            <Button 
              className={doc.estado === 'sucio'
                ? 'btn btn-danger'
                : 'btn btn-success'
              } 
              onPress={()=> navigate('/LimpiarCurso', { state: doc.data })}
            >
              {doc.anio + doc.division}
            </Button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out later since i haven't had the time to sit down and keep coding (and i still don't) but thanks for the answer!

Comment: it works! thanks! i wanted to ask something though, how do i pass the data on the state? like how do i catch it on the next screen? because of course it doesn't take the line it had before (const {num_aula, año, division, horario_retiro} = state;) and neither takes {doc.data} = state;

Comment: @Lucas Are you referring to the data passed in route state, i.e. `navigate('/LimpiarCurso', { state: doc.data })`? It should be accessed via the `location.state` object in the receiving component, i.e. `const { state } = useLocation();` where `state` is what was passed. Note that this passed ***only*** the `data` property, if you want to also access `doc.anio`, `doc.division`, etc, then these also need to be passed. You can pass the entire `doc` object though, i.e. `navigate('/LimpiarCurso', { state: doc })`.

Comment: Then on the LimpiarCurso component, i'd have to write ```const { doc } = state``` and then to access each value i'd need to just do ```{doc.anio} for example, right?```

Comment: @Lucas Close. The passed `location.state` ***is*** the "doc", so access `state.data`, `state,anio`, etc... If it helps make it clearer what "state" is then you could pass the `doc` on its own property, i.e. `navigate('/LimpiarCurso', { state: { doc } })`, then access it as `state.doc.data`, `state.doc.anio`, etc. Does this make sense?

Comment: OHHHHH, so state on its own is what i need to access, i'll try it out ASAP! Thx (i'll let you know if i can't make it work) PS: any idea of how to compare 3 values on the button class? Since estado can have up to 3 values, and depending on them it should change the color of them

Comment: Btw i made it work! tysm (i only have to do the button thingy and something else and i'm truly done)